# Is there a way to execute a custom command and cd in the same line?

Tags: command-line

Something like: `sudo java -jar /Documents/ESPlorer.jar`

Comment: That would be `cd Documents; sudo java -jar ESPlorer.jar`. On one line with a `;` in between.

Comment: Actually better `cd Documents && sudo java -jar ESPlorer.jar` with `&&` in between so the second command only gets executed if the first was successful.

Comment: Thank you. Why not post as answer? :)

Comment: `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios`  This command line tests in which mode the computer was booted, and illustrates how to make a oneliner with logical 'and' and logical 'or'.

Answer (score 3):

Followup to Jos's comment you can try &&. Below example will explain the difference:

> $ true && echo "Things went well"

Things went well

> $ false ; echo "This will always run"

This will always run

So its on you if the 2nd operation is dependant on the first operation go with `&&` else use `;`

Answer (score 3):

Your command `sudo java -jar /Documents/ESPlorer.jar` probably wouldn't do what I suspect you want it to, because /Documents probably doesn't exist in the / directory.

By itself, a better command would be `sudo java -jar ~/Documents/ESPlorer.jar`. The `~/` indicates your home folder.

You could also create ~/bin, place the .jar file in ~/bin, and because ~/bin is in your path, you could just type `sudo java -jar ESPlorer.jar`.

To answer your question, separate commands with a `;`, or better yet, with a `&&`. The latter way indicates that the first command must successfully complete before executing the second command.